# Remove next element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below HTML

```
<div name="taskNotificationsDiv">
    <div class="notificationCard">
        <span class="taskNotificationClose">x</span>
        Test
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="notificationCard">
        <span class="taskNotificationClose">x</span>
        Test
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="notificationCard">
        <span class="taskNotificationClose">x</span>
        Test
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

And I have the below script which when x is clicked removes the container from the parent.

```
  $(".taskNotificationClose").click(function (){    
        
        this.parentNode.parentNode
        .removeChild(this.parentNode);       
       
        return false;
       });
```

What I am looking for is also removing the hr which is below the div container..Can someone please have a look and let me know how it can be done.

Here's the fiddle [Fiddle][1]

I tried with the below code to find nearest hr and remove it from the parent but it's throwing an error

```
 var $hr = $(this).next('hr');
 this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild($hr);
```

Thanks
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/so3k2hpq/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.next()` function. A better approach to solve the problem with `JQuery`:

```js
$(".taskNotificationClose").click(function (){    
     $(this).parent().next("hr").remove();
     $(this).parent().remove(); 
     return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div name="taskNotificationsDiv">
    <div class="notificationCard" style="color:red;">
        <span class="taskNotificationClose">x</span>
        Test
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="notificationCard" style="color:blue;">
        <span class="taskNotificationClose">x</span>
        Test
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="notificationCard" style="color:green;">
        <span class="taskNotificationClose">x</span>
        Test
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Majed, clicking on first `x Test` element removing third element.

Comment: @Ritu I don't think so. I added colors for more clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can move 'hr' tag inside each div. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery `.next(element)` can do this

```
$(".taskNotificationClose").click(function (){    
     $(this).parent().next("hr").remove();
     $(this).parent().remove(); 
     return false;
});
```

The reason for your earlier error, is that you removed the first sibling first before calling `.next()`